# File uploading not working for larger files

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload a .zip file. It is working well for small files . But I can upload files >2MB. When I try to upload files >2 MB google chrome shows in the bottom left corner as (uploadin : --%) where -- is a no like 10. But it is stuck after 14%. After some time it shows an error like "Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset."This web page is not available.

Please help me

This is the form code

```
<form name="addnewitem" id="addnewitem" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <?php if (($succ==0) && ($message!="")) { echo "<div class='error'>".$message."</div>"; } ?>
                <?php if ($msg!="") { echo "<div class='success'>".$msg."</div>"; } ?>
                <?php if ($msg1!="") { echo "<div class='error'>".$msg1."</div>"; } ?>
                <div class="list-item">

                        <div class="form">
                            <h2>Name & Description</h2>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="left">
                                    <label>Item Title:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="right">
                                    <input name="listitemname" id="listitemname" type="text" class="input" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $_POST['listitemname']; ?>" />
                                    <em>Maximum 50 characters</em>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="left">
                                    <label>
                                        Item Description:
                                    </label></div>
                                <div class="right">
                                    <textarea name="itemdescription" id="itemdescription" cols="10" rows="5"><?php echo $_POST['itemdescription'];?></textarea>
                                    <em>Maximum 600 characters</em>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <div class="form">
                        <h2>
                            Item Files & Preview
                        </h2>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <label>
                                    Item Thumbnail:
                                </label>
                            </div>
                <div class="right"><input type="file" name="thumbnailimage" id="thumbnailimage" class="input" />
                                <em>JPG or PNG, 80 x 80 Thumbail</em>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <label>
                                    Item Rollover Preview:
                                </label></div>
                            <div class="right"><input type="file" name="rolloverimage" id="rolloverimage" class="input" />
                                <em>JPG or PNG, 190 x 190 Preview Image</em>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <label>
                                    Screenshot image 1:
                                </label></div>
                            <div class="right"><input type="file" name="themepreview1" id="themepreview1" class="input" />
                                <em>JPG or PNG, 420 x 420 Image Screenshot ( Required )</em>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                                                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <label>
                                    Screenshot image 2:
                                </label></div>
                            <div class="right"><input type="file" name="themepreview2" id="themepreview2" class="input" />
                                <em>JPG or PNG, 420 x 420 Image Screenshot ( Optional )</em>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                                                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <label>
                                    Screenshot image 3:
                                </label></div>
                            <div class="right"><input type="file" name="themepreview3" id="themepreview3" class="input" />
                                <em>JPG or PNG, 420 x 420 Image Screenshot ( Optional )</em>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                                                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <label>
                                    Screenshot image 4:
                                </label></div>
                            <div class="right"><input type="file" name="themepreview4" id="themepreview4" class="input" />
                                <em>JPG or PNG, 420 x 420 Image Screenshot ( Optional )</em>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                                                                <div class="row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <label>
                                    Item Zip File:
                                </label></div>
                            <div class="right"><input type="file" name="itemfile" id="itemfile" class="input" />
                                <em>.ZIP File Only </em>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <label>Demo URL:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <input name="demourl" id="demourl" type="text" class="input" value="<?php echo $_POST['demourl']; ?>" />
                                <em>Enter the www.themepreviewurl.com here for the item Live Preview</em>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="form">
                        <h2>
                            Category & Attributes
                        </h2>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <label>
                                    Category:
                                </label></div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <?php
                                    $getmaincategories = "SELECT category_name,category_id FROM ".$tbl_main_categories." WHERE category_status = 1";
                                    $exec_getmaincategories = mysql_query($getmaincategories);
                                    echo "<select name='categoryname' id='categoryname'>";
                                    echo "<option value='' >Select a Category Now</option>";
                                    while($rows_getmaincategories = mysql_fetch_array($exec_getmaincategories)) {
                                        $getsubcategories = "SELECT sub_category_name,sub_category_hash FROM ".$tbl_sub_categories." WHERE sub_category_status=1 AND     category_id=".$rows_getmaincategories['category_id'];
                                        $exec_getsubcategories = mysql_query($getsubcategories);
                                        echo "<option disabled='disabled' value='".$rows_getmaincategories['category_id']."'>".$rows_getmaincategories['category_name']."</option>";
                                        while($rows_getsubcategories = mysql_fetch_array($exec_getsubcategories)) {
                                        if ($_REQUEST['categoryname'] == $rows_getsubcategories['sub_category_hash']) { echo $selectedvalue = "selected='selected'"; } 
                                            echo "<option value='".$rows_getsubcategories['sub_category_hash']."' style='padding-right:inherit' $selectedvalue>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-".$rows_getsubcategories['sub_category_name']."</option>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    echo "</select>";
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <label>
                                    Compatible Browsers:<br />
                                    use 'ctrl' to select multiples
                                </label></div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <select multiple="multiple" class="select" name="browsercompatiable[]" id="browsercompatiable[]">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option value="ie7" <?php if ($_REQUEST['browsercompatiable'] == "ie7") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>IE7</option>
                                    <option value="ie8" <?php if ($_REQUEST['browsercompatiable'] == "ie8") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>IE8</option>
                                    <option value="ie9" <?php if ($_REQUEST['browsercompatiable'] == "ie9") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>IE9</option>
                                    <option value="firefox" <?php if ($_REQUEST['browsercompatiable'] == "firefox") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Firefox</option>
                                    <option value="safari" <?php if ($_REQUEST['browsercompatiable'] == "safari") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Safari</option>
                                    <option value="chrome" <?php if ($_REQUEST['browsercompatiable'] == "chrome") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Chrome</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <label>
                                    Files Includes:<br />
                                    Use 'ctrl' to select multiples
                                </label></div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <select multiple="multiple" size="5" class="select" name="filesinclude[]" id="filesinclude[]">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option value="ie7" <?php if ($_REQUEST['filesinclude'] == "ie7") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>PSD Files</option>
                                    <option value="ie8" <?php if ($_REQUEST['filesinclude'] == "ie8") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Documentation</option>
                                    <option value="ie9" <?php if ($_REQUEST['filesinclude'] == "ie9") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Multiple Layouts</option>
                                    <option value="firefox" <?php if ($_REQUEST['filesinclude'] == "firefox") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Multiple Colour Options</option>
                                    <option value="safari" <?php if ($_REQUEST['filesinclude'] == "safari") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Video Help Files</option>
                                    <option value="chrome" <?php if ($_REQUEST['filesinclude'] == "chrome") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Other</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <label>
                                    Columns:
                                </label></div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <select name="noofcolumns" id="noofcolumns">
                                <option value="">Select</option>
                                <option value="1" <?php if ($_REQUEST['noofcolumns'] == "1") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>1</option>
                                <option value="2" <?php if ($_REQUEST['noofcolumns'] == "2") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>2</option>
                                <option value="3" <?php if ($_REQUEST['noofcolumns'] == "3") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>3</option>
                                <option value="4" <?php if ($_REQUEST['noofcolumns'] == "4") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>4</option>
                                <option value="5" <?php if ($_REQUEST['noofcolumns'] == "5") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>5</option>                      
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <label>
                                    Layout:
                                </label></div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <select name="layout" id="layout">
                                <option value="">Select</option>
                                <option value="1" <?php if ($_REQUEST['layout'] == "1") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>1</option>
                                <option value="2" <?php if ($_REQUEST['layout'] == "2") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>2</option>
                                <option value="3" <?php if ($_REQUEST['layout'] == "3") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>3</option>
                                <option value="4" <?php if ($_REQUEST['layout'] == "4") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>4</option>
                                <option value="5" <?php if ($_REQUEST['layout'] == "5") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>5</option>                       
                                </select>
                                <em>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus id arcu vitae eros molestie ultricies ut sit amet nisi. Nulla facilisi.</em>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form">
                        <h2>Tags</h2>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="left">
                                <label>Tags:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <textarea name="itemtags" id="itemtags" cols="10" rows="5"><?php echo $_POST['itemtags']; ?></textarea>
                                <em>Maximum 50 characteres</em>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="botton">
                        <input name="additem" id="additem" type="submit" value="Upload Now" class="btn" />
                    </div>              
                </div>
                </form>
```

And I would like to upload >3MB files in the .zip field shown below

```
<div class="right"><input type="file" name="itemfile" id="itemfile" class="input" />
                                <em>.ZIP File Only </em>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that handles the file upload?

Comment: I have updated the file upload code.. Please take a look at it

Comment: Something to check: the [`upload_max_filesize`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) directive in php.ini defaults to 2M.

Answer (score 5):

Check upload_max_filesize, max_input_time,  **and** post_max_size in your php.ini

If the file size is very large, you may need to bump memory_limit as well.

Comment: upload_max_filesize:10M, max_input_time: 60, post_max_size : 12M. These are the values. What I wll do ?Please help me

Comment: Is it taking longer than 60 seconds? How big is the file?

Answer (score 1):

change php.ini change size and test your script.(php.ini resides in php installation directory)

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

to

```
upload_max_filesize = Required_size M
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check that your "max_input_time" option in your server is not too low, it might be why PHP is cutting you off. Else it could be a server/network infrastructure related issue:

```
echo ini_get('max_input_time');
```

If you get -1 from this, it is most probably not PHP cutting you off but something else in the loop. It can be any piece of hardware on the way to your server, but most probably the server itself or something at the server place...

Comment: Iam getting the maximum input time as 60

Comment: There you go, so after 1 minute, your server is cutting you off, you need to either change it or lower your filesize uploaded or simply change crappy host :P

Comment: You can also change ISP and increase your connexion speed, so that larger files go in faster to your server, but other users won't have that luxury

Comment: Thanks sir, How can I change it ? using ini_set('max_execution_time', 1200); ? Can I use this ?

Comment: Using ini_set wont cut it because your PHP has not started executing yet, you need to use HTACCESS or custom PHP.INI if your server allows it. Check with your hosting provider if he can instruct you how to do it or ask them to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

For large files, if you don't want to have to deal with configuring server settings (particularly if you are on shared hosting or some other hosting that doesn't give you full control over the server), one potential solution is to hand the upload off to a third party service.

For example, you could have the form do a direct post to Amazon S3 (http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-example-code/post/post_sample.html) or use a service like [Filepicker.io](https://filepicker.io)

Full disclosure: I work at Filepicker.io, but want to help out folks who are dealing with issues doing large file uploads