# How to upload mp3, mp4, 3gp files using php?

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm making a online storage and want user to upload file with category,I have successfully done with images,but I'm not able to perform it with audio & video formats ,any help?

```
<?php 

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png"); 
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/  jpg") || 
    ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) 
{ 
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) 
        { 
            echo  "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        } else {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>"; echo "Type: " .  $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>"; echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>"; 
            if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) 
                { 
                    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. "; 
                } else {  
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                        echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
                        } 
                }
} else { 
    echo "Invalid file"; 
}

?>
```

Comment: at the very least, please make your code readable when expecting an answer.

Comment: [pathinfo()](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) is your friend

Comment: `$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");` sounds like that will give you trouble with other file formats...

Comment: @Stano Is it? I tried to give it a readable shape. But looks like only I can't read them properly.

Comment: What if i add "3gp","mp4" in allowed ext. And there respective mime types in the code ?

Comment: Also, it is not clear if you are asking why the the posted code does not work for videos (mostly because you are only allowing image extensions/mimes), or if thats what you were using for images that worked before and asking how to extend it to work for videos also.

Comment: Right, @Stano i tried to add via mime-types,  but not seem to be helpfull, it gives error, any idea how to edit this code & allow audio,video files.. ,,any help?

Comment: [Tested the file upload](http://pastebin.com/8KqPFk27) and those mime types are: for .mp3 ~ `audio/mpeg` and for .mp4 ~ `video/mp4`. For big filesizes you will need to adjust `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size` and `max_input_time` settings in `php.ini`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140356/file-uploading-not-working-for-larger-files#11140481 this seems to be that problem.

Comment: Thanks @Stano ,,,for the mime-types. And for other requirements, its working fine,,,

Comment: Glad i could help. I would prefer to use XeonCross's function to recognize a true mime type (it works almost everywhere), and only in case it doesn't work (returns false or null), use simple [file extension checking](http://www.darian-brown.com/php-function-to-get-file-mime-type/).

Answer (score 3):

Your code is already broken. `$_FILES[$file]["type"]` is meaningless. It is supplied by the browser uploading the file, not by the server, and as such is frequently missing or wrong. It should be ignored.

Changing the initial condition to simply:

```
if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
```

will fix that. You will need to increase the size limit (currently 20000 = 20 KB), though, as that will obviously be too little for a video file. :)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than checking the extension `.[a-z]` of the file (which can be changed) - why not check the file itself? (even `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` can lie)

```
function get_mime($file) {
  if (function_exists("finfo_file")) {
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
    finfo_close($finfo);
    return $mime;
  } else if (function_exists("mime_content_type")) {
    return mime_content_type($file);
  } else if (!stristr(ini_get("disable_functions"), "shell_exec")) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/134930/1593459
    $file = escapeshellarg($file);
    $mime = shell_exec("file -bi " . $file);
    return $mime;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12191939/99923

Comment: im new to file-uploads, i didn't get where to post your code, ,any help ?

Comment: `if(get_mime($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]) === 'image/jpeg') // yay!`

Comment: What type of file are you uploading? Also test to see which of the parsers is actually running: `var_dump(function_exists("finfo_file"),function_exists("mime_content_type"), stristr(ini_get("disable_functions"), "shell_exec"));`

Comment: .jpg. I am testing it in Windows and that NULL comes from the $mime = shell_exec("file -bi " . $file); branch. Suppose this function work will be working well in Linux.

Comment: The file extension is what matters most here. Allowing through a file that looks like a JPEG but has a `.php` extension would be a major security risk.

Comment: @duskwuff, yes, you should be storing the cleaned user-supplied name in a database and renaming the file based on the actual mime type for the server storage.

Answer (score 1):

for my opinion, change php.ini file like.. 'upload_max_filesize= 500M' , 'post_max_size=500M', 'memory_limit=250M', 'max_input_time=45000' and 'max_execution_time=30000'.

I edited this php.ini file, and i can able to upload audio and video file.